# refetch different query from retry of another query in React Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In my solution, I am wrapping React Query's `useQuery` hook with my own to have a specific retry logic:

```js
export function useMyQuery(key, queryFn, options = {}) {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const query = useReactQuery(key, queryFn, {
        ...options,
        retry: async(count, error) => await retry(count, error, queryClient),
    });

    return query;
}
```

The `retry` function itself is as follows:

```js
export async function retry(count, error, queryClient) {
    
    if (error?.statusCode === 401) {
        // caught 401, trying to refresh token;

        if (await refreshToken(queryClient)) {
            queryClient.refetchQueries('fetchSession');
            return true;
        }
    }


    // Retry 3 times
    return count < 3;
}
```

and, finally my `fetchSession` query looks like this:

```js
const { data } = useQuery('fetchSession', () => {
 console.log('fetching new session...');
 return Auth.currentSession();
})
```

My Goal is to trigger refetch of the "fetchSession" query after I have successfully refreshed the token in the code above, however, the query is never refetched i.e. the query body is never run after the token is refreshed. Besides using `refetchQueries` method on `queryClient`, I have also tried `invalidateQueries` to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retry` function is not async - it expects you to return a `boolean`, not a `Promise<boolean>`, so that doesn't work.

I would do this logic either with an axios interceptor (if you are using that), or just in your queryFn:

```
useQuery('fetchSession', async () => {
 try {
   const { data } = await axios.get(...)
   return data
 } catch(error) {
    if (error.statuscode === 401) {
        const token = await refreshToken(queryClient))
        const { data } = await axios.get(...) // pass token here? don't know how this works for you :)
        return data
    } else {
        throw error
    }
 }
})
```